# A simple problem about drawarrow in METAPOST

Tags: metapost

I am a beginner of METAPOST. I simply want to draw an arrow. I type the following code in TeXstudio 2.11.0:

```
% This program uses the METAPOST language to produce the eps file of {fig:R_5}.
% In TeXstudio, click Tools->Commands->MetaPost to compile this file.

prologues:=3;
filenametemplate "%j.eps";

input boxes
beginfig(1);
    % The upper bound of $z_1$.
    z1UB=8.6cm;

    % Draw the $z_1$-axis.
    drawarrow (0,0)--(z1UB,0);  
endfig;
end;
```

Then I click on Tools->Commands->MetaPost to compile the above file. Out of my expectation, I get the following error messages:

```
Process started: mpost.exe -interaction=nonstopmode R_5.mp

Process exited with error(s)
```

The log file is:

```
This is MetaPost, version 1.803 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)  2 SEP 2016 16:49
**R_5.mp
(mpost.mp (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004) ) (./R_5.mp
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/boxes.mp)
>> (x1UB,y1UB)
>> 243.77965
! Equation cannot be performed (pair=numeric).
<to be read again> 
                   ;
l.10 ^^Iz1UB=8.6cm;

I'm sorry, but I don't know how to make such things equal.
(See the two expressions just above the error message.)

! Missing `)' has been inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
l.13     drawarrow (0,0)--(z1UB,
                                0);  
I found no right delimiter to match a left one. So I've
put one in, behind the scenes; this may fix the problem.

>> x1UB
! Undefined x coordinate has been replaced by 0.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
l.13     drawarrow (0,0)--(z1UB,
                                0);  
I need a `known' x value for this part of the path.
The value I found (see above) was no good;
so I'll try to keep going by using zero instead.
(Chapter 27 of The METAFONTbook explains that
you might want to type `I ???' now.)

>> y1UB
! Undefined y coordinate has been replaced by 0.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
l.13     drawarrow (0,0)--(z1UB,
                                0);  
I need a `known' y value for this part of the path.
The value I found (see above) was no good;
so I'll try to keep going by using zero instead.
(Chapter 27 of The METAFONTbook explains that
you might want to type `I ???' now.)

! Extra tokens will be flushed.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
<argument> ,
            0)
_finarr->draw._apth(TEXT0)
                          ;filldraw.arrowhead._apth(TEXT0)
<to be read again> 
                   ;
l.13     drawarrow (0,0)--(z1UB,0);

I've just read as much of that statement as I could fathom,
so a semicolon should have been next. It's very puzzling...
but I'll try to get myself back together, by ignoring
everything up to the next `;'. Please insert a semicolon
now in front of anything that you don't want me to delete.
(See Chapter 27 of The METAFONTbook for an example.)

! Extra tokens will be flushed.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
<argument> ,
            0)
_finarr->...TEXT0);filldraw.arrowhead._apth(TEXT0)

<to be read again> 
                   ;
l.13     drawarrow (0,0)--(z1UB,0);

I've just read as much of that statement as I could fathom,
so a semicolon should have been next. It's very puzzling...
but I'll try to get myself back together, by ignoring
everything up to the next `;'. Please insert a semicolon
now in front of anything that you don't want me to delete.
(See Chapter 27 of The METAFONTbook for an example.)

[1] )
1 output file written: R_5.eps
```

Could you please tell me how to write the correct code? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You need to declare variable types. If I replace `z1UB` by just `z`,  and declare it as `numeric z;`, then this MWE compiles just fine

Comment: @daleif Thank you for your comment. After modifying my code according to your comment, the code works. But I don't understand why do we need to replace `z1UB` by `z`?

Comment: @daleif No, `numeric z` is a bad error; never name a numeric variable as `z`

Comment: `z1UB` is a pair. So `z1UB=(8.6cm,8.6cm);`
`drawarrow (0,0)--z1UB;`
will be compiled without errors, though
I don't know what result you want.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comment. Where can I find the rules of naming variable in METAPOST?

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Thank you for your comment. After modifying my code according to your comment, my code runs well. :-)

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu Just use `x` and `y` for coordinates and `z` for the corresponding pair.

Comment: @egreg, ahh, yes of course, just wanted to make it compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard convention in Metafont/Metapost is that `z` (with subscripts) denotes a *pair*. So you cannot set `z1UB=8.6cm`.

When you do

```
z1=(1,2);
```

you're basically doing

```
x1=1;y1=2;
```

Use a different name for the variable.

Alternatively,

```
prologues:=3;
filenametemplate "%j.eps";

input boxes
beginfig(1);
    % The upper bound of $z_1$.
    z1UB=(8.6cm,0);

    % Draw the $z_1$-axis.
    drawarrow (0,0)--z1UB;
endfig;
end;
```

You can also use

```
    drawarrow origin--z1UB;
```